# Restrict google assistant action from being used on iphone

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I've deployed a Google Assistant action using Node.js and DialogFlow, which tells the user his current location using Google maps API but it doesn't seem to work on iPhone as iPhone doesn't provide GPS location to the action. Can I make it work on iPhone or restrict it from being used on iPhone.Here is the link to the action directory page-[Find my Location](https://assistant.google.com/services/a/uid/000000f8b01b12dd?hl=en-US&source=web)

Answer (score 1):

There's no specific way to restrict access to a specific type of phone. Although you can check the [surface capabilities](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/surface-capabilities), you cannot disambiguate between Android and iPhones.

Does the Google Assistant app on the iPhone have any location access? If you ask 'Where am I?' will it give the answer?

What are you getting after you make the location permission request? Do you get a permission denied response, or an undefined location?

Comment: Siri answers the question with the location but for Google Assistant it gives undefined location.

Comment: It seems like you will need to give the Google Assistant app permission to your location. It may be something that needs to be enabled in your phone settings. Location in Google Assistant is generally available, and that may explain why your action is not getting location.